# Get and Post data in Flask request

Tags: post, flask, get, insomnia

Hello and thanks in advance for any help.
I am trying to set up a ReactJS & Flask Web App, but i am having trouble getting the data into Flask, i am using Insomnia to test send the data to Flask, and the POST request returns code 200, but i keep on getting the error on the printscreen below, **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment**. The string is not passed to the TTS (text-to-speech) class for processing, when i use direct assignment for the strings on the comented code bellow the imports works fine.

I have tried to send the data with JSON, now i am trying with form format, it returns the same error.

Can you help me, please, and take a look at my code ?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import speak

# text = "AI AI minha machadinha !!"
# lang = "pt"

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../static/dist", template_folder="../static")
@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/hello", methods=["GET","POST"])
def hello():
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.form["text"]
        lang = request.form["lang"]
        print("passou")
    return speak.get_speak(text,lang)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

[Insomnia code 200 message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0znZ.jpg)

[error on console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sv4r.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
@app.route("/hello", methods=["GET","POST"])
def hello():
    text = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.form["text"]
        lang = request.form["lang"]
        print("passou")
        return speak.get_speak(text,lang)
```

This is beacause your text is defined inside if condition and your return is outside the if condition. You need to define it above the if and give it a default value.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I tried and solved that error, but now is passing a empty string into the get_speak function, with some debugging with a print i know it enters the get_speak function but with empty variables. Any idea why does it enter the if condition (if it would not enter the if condition it wouldn't return the get_speak function i believe ?) and does not assign the form values ? I have tried to change it to JSON, change it to GET instead of POST and similar errors occur...

Comment: I guess there is some issue with the request.form then , you’re not getting the values from the front end properly it seems!

Comment: I just built a very simple front end template with a button to trigger the function, and i am using Insomnia to test send the data to Flask,  if you check out the first picture in my original post, you can see the 200 message, seems everything is ok...

Comment: Try to return it inside the if block. Have edited my code.

Comment: This is what i get now :


File "/home/kajo/Desktop/TTS/TextToSpeech/server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.